# Text overflowing on div with inline block

Tags: html, css

I have a inline block within a div that has some text contents. The text contents are overflowing if the display is set to inline...

http://jsfiddle.net/76d9twoy/

HTML & CSS

```
<div id="leftdiv">
</div>
<div id="rightdiv">
       <div id="nametag">Simba Animated Plush Battery Operated Sitting Talking Tom, Multi Color (9-inch)<div>
       <div id="pricetag">10.00$<div>
       <div id="quantitytag">10<div>
</div>



#leftdiv{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue

}

#rightdiv{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow
}
#nametag{
    width:200px;
    display:inline;

}
```

Question: How do I text wrap the nametag contents?

Comment: I have edited it with the question..Need to wrap the contents for the nametag

Comment: Still can't understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: Ok so nametag is 200px wide and you want text to wrap within that.  Like you said if you just take out inline then it will work.

Comment: I don't really get it either. Can you try to formulate again?

Comment: I need to contain the text " Simba Animated Plush Battery Operated Sitting Talking Tom, 2: Multi Color (9-inch)" within 200px, so that I can display the price and quantity next to it.

Comment: Remove `display:inline;` or change it to `display:inline-block;`

Comment: use inline-block/block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But what is the problem?
if you want it inline-block than can you do this to fix it:
css:

```
#nametag{
width:200px;
display:inline-block; //set to inline-block
}

#rightdiv{
float:left;
width:400px;
height:auto; //set to auto
background-color:yellow
}
```

than at this Jquery code to the page to set the leftdiv height the same as the rightdiv

Jquery:

```
$('#leftdiv').css( 'height', $('#rightdiv').height());
```

than you get this a result http://jsfiddle.net/76d9twoy/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch from inline to inline-block if you want them to fit next to each other.
In addition, be careful with your tags. Your divs were not closed. You must use:

```
</div>
```

To fix the single line, use white-space property.

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/76d9twoy/2/